# I can't upgrade from adb version 1.0.29

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to interface my nexus 7 with my linux mint machine. The device always shows as offline. I understand that this problem comes from having an adb older than 1.0.31. I keep installing the platform tools rev 21.1 which as of last month is the newest version which should install adb 1.0.31, but every time I run the command 'adb version' it comes back saying it is version 1.0.29. Is there another way to get it to upgrade?

Answer (score 34):

This solved this problem (running old adb) on Ubuntu:

1. unplug device
2. adb kill-server
3. adb version

   - Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.29
4. cd to android sdk dir

   - cd /home/XXX/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/platform-tools/
5. copy new adb to /usr/bin

   - sudo cp adb /usr/bin/
6. adb version

   - Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31
7. adb kill-server
8. adb devices

   - daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
   - daemon started successfully *
     List of devices attached
9. plug in the device, and on the device dialog about RSA appeared
10. accept on device
11. adb devices

    - List of devices attached
    - 04cefca0e29085aa  device

Comment: This worked for me!  I wanted to add, after step 5, I had to close Terminal and re-open.  Thanks!

Comment: Wow!! This actually helped me a lot.. I had not updated the adb.. I had updated the SDK manager but the adb was still using the old version i.e 1.0.29 not the new one 1.0.31. The steps listed above were very helpful... Now cmd identifies it as a device and no longer shows it as "offline" (Android devices 4.2.2)

Comment: This case is also valid for Windows. The difference is that the folder you should be checking is C:\Windows or C:\Windows\System32

Answer (score 2):

**Answer for Windows:**

You need to check where's your latest driver located and put this value in **PATH** system variable. To do so:

1. Open Android SDK Manager (Android Studio/Tools/Android/SDK Manager; or from Eclipse).
2. In the top left corner (just under menu) you'll see "SDK Path". This is where latest driver located.
3. Open `Control Panel\System and Security\System`, click on "Advanced system settings", find button "Enviroment Variables...".
4. Find the PATH variable in the list (check both lists). Find the old platrorm-tools path. Replace the old path to new onreplace what you have there to SDK Path + "platform-tools" (example "c:\Android2013\sdk\platform-tools").

Answer (score 1):

Following two steps can be performed to solve this issue.

1. May be there is another `adb` running in the background. Use `adb kill-server` to stop the adb servers, and restart `adb`.
2. If you want to update `adb`, it can be done by running SDK Manager from the install SDK location. Upgrade "Platform Tools" to upgrade adb.
3. The problem stated above may be the same as following. Please check the following post.
   [Android 4.2.2 - adb offline, even after SDK upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073165/android-4-2-2-adb-offline-even-after-sdk-upgrade)

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I actually have tried killing the server and restarting, unplugging the device, restarting the computer and the nexus, turning off and on usb debugging on the nexus, reinstalling the sdk and upgrading the platform tools several times over from the manager and from the commandline.

Comment: My sdk versions are currently: API 17, SDK Tools Rev. 21.1 and platform tools 16.0.2. These are the newest tools available, yet somehow when I run the command "adb version" it returns "1.0.29" which is too old to use in debugging an android 4.2.2 device. Does anyone know where I can just download a newer copy of adb?

Answer (score 0):

You should first check whether proper drivers are installed for your device or not.
The following link can help you.

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Also, if you want to upgrade `adb` there is another way for that.
Go to: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/android-tools/

Click on the quantal version (4.2.2-something).
Download the .xz, .dsc, and .tar.gz and ten:

`# sudo apt-get build-dep android-tools`

`# sudo apt-get install libselinux-dev`

`# dpkg-source -x android-tools*.dsc`

`# cd android-tools*`

`# fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage`

`# cd ..`

`# sudo dpkg -i android-tools-adb*`

This solution was presented here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/android-tools/+bug/1131163

Comment: Thank you so much. Your directions for updating the adb worked! It debugs every time now! Now I can get on with my project.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution i found ever is:

1. Check ur adb version by using command: adb version for windows and ./adb version for Linux system
2. if it showing 1.0.29 please upgrade it to 1.0.31 because 1.0.29  will not rspond for JB 4.2.X
3. it will fix ur device offline problem
4. if ur system already have the new adb(1.0.31) and facing this problem, in that case open sdk and upgrade plateform tool to 16.0.1
5. restart ur device atleast one time.. :)
   it will work fine for all the devices...

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me.Updating the sdk still showed the older 1.0.29 version.
I downloaded the 1.0.31 version from [here](https://code.google.com/p/sudolee/downloads/detail?name=adb-fastboot.zip&can=2&q=) and replaced the old adb with this and it worked.
Now the device is recognized by adb in 4.2.2.
Hope this helps someone and saves some time.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem on my Windows machine by following these steps:

1. Install updates from SDK Manager
2. Copy the corresponding adb files (dlls and exe) to C:\Windows\System32
3. adb kill-server
4. adb version

Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved by **updating** the Android Studio.

you can get the update by 
**choosing Help > Check for Updates**
(Android Studio > Check for Updates on macOS)